# Fluorophores with high quantum yield and low lifetime

Tags: fluorescence, dye, emission

Does anyone know of any fluorophore or family of fluorophores with a relatively high fluorescence quantum yield (larger than 0.1) and a short lifetime (below hundreds of picoseconds)?

I have been checking and rhodamines and coumarins, for example, have very large quantum yields, as [Alexa Fluor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexa_Fluor) dyes, but the lifetimes are of the order of the nanoseconds.

Comment: Good question. You could shorten the lifetime by adding quenchers, e.g., nitromethane, oxygen gas or various “heavy atoms”, but that reduces the quantum efficiencies as well. I hope you get a good answer!